# Join tables in Hive using LIKE

Tags: join, hiveql

I am joining `tbl_A` to `tbl_B`, on column `CustomerID` in `tbl_A` to column `Output` in `tbl_B` which contains `customer ID`. However, `tbl_B` has all other information in related rows that I do not want to lose when joining. I tried to `join` using `like`, but I lost rows that did not contain `customer ID` in the output column.

[image][image]

Here is my join query in Hive:

```
select a.*, b.Output from tbl_A a
left join tbl_B b
On b.Output like concat('%', a.CustomerID, '%')
```

However, I lose other rows from output.

Comment: Interesting. You claim that this code was executed without an error?

Comment: Please read and act on [mcve]. PS If you want all rows from b, you need b left join a, or a right join b.

Comment: If you are able to run this without an error could you share your Hive version please? As far as I know, Hive only allows equi-joins; in other words, it does not allow join phrase to be in form `ON b.Output like concat('%', a.CustomerID, '%')`. see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25850819/1434041

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest first extract all ID's from free floating field which in your case is 'Output' column in table B into a separate table. Then join this table with ID's to Table B again to populate in each row the ID and then this second joined table which is table B with ID's to table A.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could also achieve the objective by a simple hive query like this :)

```sql
select a.*, b.Output 
from tbl_A a, tbl_B b
where b.Output like concat('%', a.CustomerID, '%')
```